# How to change a dictionary key into a value

Tags: python

I have been trying to user Beautiful Soup to parse a website and get necessary data. Now that I have the data I want to use pandas to organize the data but for that I want to make a well-structured dictionary.

The data that I have scraped and cleaned up is in the dictionary `data_dict`. Here, the keys are the names of the turtles and the values are some information about the corresponding turtle.

```
data_dict = {'Aesop': ['AGE: 7 Years Old', 'WEIGHT: 6 lbs', 'SEX: Female', 'BREED: African Aquatic Sideneck Turtle', 'SOURCE: found in Lake Erie'], 'Caesar': ['AGE: 2 Years Old', 'WEIGHT: 4 lbs', 'SEX: Male', 'BREED: Greek Tortoise', 'SOURCE: hatched in house'], 'Sulla': ['AGE: 1 Year Old', 'WEIGHT: 1 lb', 'SEX: Male', 'BREED: African Aquatic Sideneck Turtle', 'SOURCE: found in Lake Erie']}
```

Now, I wanted the keys of this dictionary to be something like "turtle_1" and the next one "turtle_2" and so on. So I wrote the code:

```
name_num = 1
for name in list(data_dict.keys()):
    data_dict["turtle_"+str(name_num)] = data_dict.pop(name)
    name_num += 1
```

This changed the keys from `"Aesop"`.... (and so on) to `"turtle_1"`.... and so on. Now I want the name of the turtle (that was previously the key) to be a value of the corresponding key. I want `data_dict` to look something like this:

```
data_dict = {'turtle_1': ['AGE: 7 Years Old', 'WEIGHT: 6 lbs', 'SEX: Female', 'BREED: African Aquatic Sideneck Turtle', 'SOURCE: found in Lake Erie', 'NAME: Aesop'], 'turtle_2': ['AGE: 2 Years Old', 'WEIGHT: 4 lbs', 'SEX: Male', 'BREED: Greek Tortoise', 'SOURCE: hatched in house', 'NAME: Caesar'], 'turtle_3': ['AGE: 1 Year Old', 'WEIGHT: 1 lb', 'SEX: Male', 'BREED: African Aquatic Sideneck Turtle', 'SOURCE: found in Lake Erie', 'NAME: Sulla']}
```

So, the keys get a new value which is the name of each turtle. Thanks and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: just a suggestion, i think lists arent really suited for the information you're trying to convey, and a nested dict might be just what you need.

Comment: @ArafatKhan Just add name property to the value array for each turtle in the for loop. You can achieve that by adding one line to your code. See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append name:

```
data_dict = {'Aesop': ['AGE: 7 Years Old', 'WEIGHT: 6 lbs', 'SEX: Female', 'BREED: African Aquatic Sideneck Turtle', 'SOURCE: found in Lake Erie'], 'Caesar': ['AGE: 2 Years Old', 'WEIGHT: 4 lbs',
                                                                                                                                                               'SEX: Male', 'BREED: Greek Tortoise', 'SOURCE: hatched in house'], 'Sulla': ['AGE: 1 Year Old', 'WEIGHT: 1 lb', 'SEX: Male', 'BREED: African Aquatic Sideneck Turtle', 'SOURCE: found in Lake Erie']}
name_num = 1
for name in list(data_dict.keys()):
    data_dict["turtle_"+str(name_num)] = data_dict.pop(name)
    data_dict["turtle_"+str(name_num)].append('NAME: '+name)
    name_num += 1

print(data_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
key_map = {}

for i,k in enumerate(data_dict.keys()):
    key_map['turtle_'+str(i+1)] = k # store reverse map from turtle_1 -> name1
    data_dict['turtle_'+str(i+1)] = data_dict.pop(k)
```

- now you can access which turtle is correspond to `turtle_1` using `key_map`.

```
>>> key_map
{'turtle_1': 'Aesop', 'turtle_2': 'Caesar', 'turtle_3': 'Sulla'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In-place :** 
Just add another element to the list corresponding to the key (or name).

```
key_count = 1
for name in list(data_dict.keys()):
    newlist = data_dict.pop(name)
    newlist.append('NAME : ' + name)
    data_dict['turtle_' + str(key_count)] = newlist
    key_count = key_count +1
```